# Closed form expression for the k-th term of a sequence.

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series

Let 
$$
x_{n+1} =  \left\{ \begin{array}{c} x_{n}^2 & \mbox{if $b_{n+1}=1$} \\ \alpha x_n & \mbox{if $b_{n+1}=0$}\end{array} \right. ,
$$
for $n\ge 0$ and $\alpha > 1$. Can we write $x_k$ in terms of $x_0$ and $P$ where
$$
P = \sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i.
$$
For $\alpha=1$, 
$$
x_k = x_0^{\left( 2^P \right)}.
$$
I am unable to figure out the expression for any $\alpha>1$.

Comment: I'm sure $x_k$ depends on the order of the $b_i$s if $\alpha^2 \ne 1$

Comment: exactly! and that's why I thought that $P$ alone may not be sufficient to describe it.

Comment: What's the connection between $x_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: they are independent

Comment: what is $b_n$ then?

Comment: Assume, $b_n \in \{0,1\}$ are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $\alpha > 1$ and $x_0 \ne 0$.  For $b_1 = 0, b_2 = 1$ you have $x_2 = \alpha^2 x_0^2$ and for $b_1 = 1, b_2 = 0$ you have $x_2 = \alpha x_0^2$.  These aren't equal, so $x_2$ doesn't depend on $x_0$ and $P = b_1 + b_2$ alone.